# Accessing Gradle inputs in task constructor

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to Gradle and having troubles creating a custom Task that can correctly determine when it's up to date.  I'd like to set the member decorated with @OutputFile in the custom task's constructor based off the other input variables, but they all set to the defaults in the constructor.  I do see the values set correctly in the TaskAction.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I've combed the docs, tried to dig up examples and I'm not finding much.

Here is a simplified version of the build script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

class TestTask extends DefaultTask {

   @Input
   String [] className = []

   @Input
   String outputDir = ""

   @OutputFile
   File targetFile

   TestTask() {
   println("Constructor")
   println("outputDir: " + outputDir)
   // I'd like to set the targetFile here, based on the outputDir and className
   }

   @TaskAction
   def action() {
      println("Action")
      println("outputDir: " + outputDir )     
   }
}
task runTest_Opus(type:TestTask) {
   className = ['class.name.here']
   outputDir = 'jni/outputDir/'
}

task runAll {
   dependsOn tasks.withType(TestTask)
}


build.dependsOn.add("runAll")
```

Comment: Why not `@OutputDirectory File outputDir` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value of `targetFile` is derived then use a getter method instead of an instance field.

```
@OutputFile
File getTargetFile() {
    // code to resolve output file based on other inputs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact needs, `@OutputDirectory File outputDir` could be an easy solution. Derived defaults are more commonly set by a plugin. In any case, their computation needs to be deferred in one way or another (e.g. `project.afterEvaluate { ... }`).

Comment: My output directory as other files in it, including one for input.  When I used the directory name the task always reported upToDate even if I removed the file generated from the build.

Comment: That's what `@OutputDirectory` means. Whenever possible, each task should have its own output directory that doesn't contain any other files.